# How can I import a module using import_module to solve 'ModuleNotFoundError' from test code

Tags: python, unit-testing

Here's the example.

src

- main

  - import

    - job.py
    - util.py
- test

  - import

    - test_job.py

in job.py

```
from util import *


def do_the_job():
    return get_greeting() + ' world!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(do_the_job())
```

in util.py

```
def get_greeting():
    return 'Hello'
```

in test_job.py

```
import importlib
import unittest

target_module = importlib.import_module('src.main.import.job')


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_hello_world(self):
        self.assertEqual(target_module.do_the_job(), 'Hello world!')


def test_suite():
    return unittest.makeSuite(MyTest)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(test_suite())
```

OUTPUT:
File "/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/TestProj/src/main/import/job.py", line 1, in 
from util import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'util'

I know the solution for this error is to import 'util' in test code but I can't because of the name of the package 'import'(and can't change it for certain reasons as well).
As a workaround I used *importlib.import_module('src.main.import.util')* but it doesn't help in this case.

How can I import a module to solve this error?

Comment: no it doesn't work for me, it's about pytest so unable to apply to this case

Comment: Ah, sorry, misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I should've done is to synchronize module path between source code and test code to make tc be able to find a module. In above example, I changed an importing way like below.

I wanted to import as same as *from..import* statement so that I don't have to type util everytime when I use it but couldn't find it.

In job.py

```
import importlib


def do_the_job():
    util = importlib.import_module('src.main.import.util')
    return util.get_greeting() + ' world!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(do_the_job())
```